# NSDictionary show null after converted

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nslog

```
NSString *profilestring = [self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"profilestrings"];
NSDictionary *dicProfile = [profilestring propertyListFromStringsFileFormat];
NSLog(@"--->>%@",profilestring);
NSLog(@">>%@",dicProfile);
```

`self.userDefaults` is NSUserDefaults, and `NSLog(@"--->>%@",profilestring);` prints a string, such as

```
{
    useraddtime = 1401444211;
    userage = 11;
    usernickname = XJD;
    usersex = 1;
    userstatus = 1;
}
```

but `NSLog(@">>%@",dicProfile);` prints `(null)`,  can you help me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the statement: `NSDictionary *dicProfile = [profilestring propertyListFromStringsFileFormat];`?

Comment: @DMusic Your string i.e profilestring is not in .strings file format

Comment: @DMusic use propertyList instead of propertyListFromStringsFileFormat method on profilestring

Answer (score 1):

Apples documentation says the keys and values themselves are always strings enclosed in straight quotation marks. Your keys and values are not enclosed in quotation marks. The string i.e profilestring should look like this

```
{
"useraddtime" = "1401444211";
"userage" = "11";
"usernickname" = "XJD";
"usersex" = "1";
"userstatus" = "1";
```

}

Comment: I doubt that the OP really wants ".strings file format", probably wants "plist" format.

Comment: @Zaph The method propertyListFromStringsFileFormat requires .string file formatted string

Comment: Not really, plist format supports objects other than strings.

Comment: @Zaph for plist formatted string you need to use the method propertyList

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `[self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"profilestrings"]` is actually a `NSDictionary` so you could do something like

```
NSDictionary *dicProfile = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"profilestrings"]];
```